# Hadoop distributed version of K-Means?

Tags: hadoop, k-means

Wondering if there is an open source implementation for Hadoop distributed version of K-Means? Ask for Hadoop since data is big which cannot be hold into a single box.

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: Yes, there is, Mahaout has several k-means implementation e.g.: https://mahout.apache.org/users/clustering/k-means-clustering.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is, Mahaout has several k-means implementation e.g.: mahout.apache.org/users/clustering/k-means-clustering.html

Comment: The performance however is so bad, that it almost always is faster to run a fast k-means implementation on a single host instead of paying the massive overhead of Mahout and Hadoop... (**never use Hadoop if your data fits into main memory**)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [spark](https://spark.apache.org/) for this. Spark implements [KMeans](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-clustering.html). Spark uses RDD (Resilient Distributed Dataset). Your data are distributed on your cluster and each node process closest data.

Spark's performances can be better than Mahout because some of interemediate process are not written on HDFS.